# java anonymous class as parameter with new methods

Tags: java, anonymous-class

When I search for the method by reflection it shows the newly provided method. But I don't know how to invoke that method, if someone has got  any idea how to do it please tell me.

```
//some pakage
pakage xyz;

class A {
    // a simple method of class A
    public void aMethod() {
        //simple print statement
        System.out.println("A class method");
    }
}

class B {
    // a method of class B that takes A types as an argument
    public void bMethod(A arg) {
        Class c = Class.forName("xyz.A");

        Method[] methods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            System.out.println(method.getName());
        }
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B bObj = new B();
        bObj.bMethod(new A() {
            public void anotherMethod() {
                System.out.println("another method");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code first.

Comment: I formatted your question and your code, and fixed the obvious mistakes. Next time, I'll just downvote. Take some care when writing a question.

Comment: You should also explain what you're trying to achieve, at a much higher level. Why are you using reflection? Why are you using such anonymous classes with additional methods that no one can call. But anyway, if you want to find this additional method, you need to get the methods of the class of `arg`. Not the methods of A.

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to invoke the method on particular object:

```
public void invokeSomeMethodOnA(A arg, String methodName) {
    Method method = arg.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName);

    //To invoke the method:
    method.invoke(arg, parameters here);
}
```

Comment: method.invoke(obj, parameters here);is it is the same object(obj) in parameter?

Comment: Yes, the method will be invoked on the same object as in parameter.

Comment: Ok Thank You krzysztof-cichocki

Answer (score 0):

I suppose maybe this is what you want.

```
package xyz;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class A {
    // a simple method of class A
    public void aMethod() {
        //simple print statement
        System.out.println("A class method");
    }
}

class B {
    // a method of class B that takes A types as an argument
    public void bMethod(A arg) throws Exception {
        Class c = Class.forName(arg.getClass().getName());

        Method[] methods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            System.out.println(method.getName());
            method.invoke(arg);
        }
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        B bObj = new B();
        bObj.bMethod(new A() {
            public void anotherMethod() {
                System.out.println("another method");
            }
        });
    }
}
```